# How to find $B$ by solving the following linear system: $s_k$ $B$ ${s_k}^T$ $=1,$

Tags: systems-of-equations, matlab, matrix-equations

How to find $B$ by solving the following linear system: 
 
 
$s_k$ $B$ ${s_k}^T$ $=1,$   $\qquad$  for $k=1 ... ,p$. 
 
Where   $s_k$ is a $1\times3$ row_vector  from the matrix

$S= [s_1   ...     s_p]^T=\begin{pmatrix}
     {s_1}_x & {s_1}_y & {s_1}_z \\
          \vdots  & \vdots& \vdots \\
     {s_p}_x  & {s_p}_y  & {s_p}_z  \\   
     \end{pmatrix}$

and p $\ge$ 6

This system is supposed to find the 6 entries of a $3\times3$ symmetric matrix. 
 
I would like to use Matlab to find this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the problem ? If $p=6$, then one has a linear system of $6$ equations in the $6$ unknowns $b_{i,j}$, $i\leq j$. Write explicitly these equations.  In general, the determinant of this system is non-zero and there is a unique solution.